# Classification figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to generate a figure like this in Tikz. But, I have not been able to find an example that I can addapt. Do anybody knows of an example that I can use.

[image]

Comment: searching the site for "tikz circular text" turned up this that may get you started https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569706/1090

Comment: I have this link for You:
[https://awesomeopensource.com/project/FriendlyUser/LatexDiagrams](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/FriendlyUser/LatexDiagrams) I hope is useful for You.