# How to boldface text inside sunburst chart and increase font size a little?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, bold

I have used the help of [How to make a sunburst chart in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569675/how-to-make-a-sunburst-chart-in-latex) and customized it to my need for creating sunburst chart. I need to boldface all the text inside it, and if possible, increase the size of text inside it. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[border=0.05in]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{pear}{rgb}{0.82, 0.89, 0.19}
\definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.71, 0.49, 0.86}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text}
\newlength{\layerwd}
\newcounter{outermost}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{onion}{sm}{%*= draw axes; #1: thickness of each annulus
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setlength{\layerwd}{#2}%
        \setcounter{outermost}{0}
    }{%
        \foreach \A in {0,...,\theoutermost}{\draw[thick,] (0,0) circle (\A*\layerwd+\layerwd);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% *=text on a circular path; [optional fill color]; #3 layer;
% #4 start angle; #5 stop angle; #6 [optional text]
%% angles are counterclockwise in degrees
\NewDocumentCommand{\annulus}{sO{lightgray}mmmo}{%
    \filldraw[thick,fill=#2,] (#4:#3*\layerwd) %% start here
    arc [radius=#3*\layerwd, start angle=#4, delta angle=#5-#4] %% inner arc
    -- (#5:#3*\layerwd+\layerwd) %% move out
    arc [radius=#3*\layerwd+\layerwd, start angle=#5, delta angle=#4-#5,] %% outer arc
    -- cycle; %% Back to the beginnning
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{(#5-#4)/2 +#4} %% Locate the middle of the arc
    \IfNoValueF{#6}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {%
            \begingroup
            %% text is always rightside-up:
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpTF}{ifthenelse(\tmp>180,"false","true")}
            \def\\{\space} %% A safety precaution, \\ = space on decorated text
            \path[rotate=\tmp-180,postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    raise=-3pt,
                    text align={align=center},
                    reverse path=\rpTF,
                    text=#6
                }
            }] (0,0) circle (#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd);
            \endgroup
        }%% 
        {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpTF}{ifthenelse(\tmp>180,\tmp+90,\tmp-90)}
            \node[inner sep=0pt, %%% If there is text, print it
            text width=#3*\layerwd*3+\layerwd,
            align=center,
            rotate=\rpTF,
            font=\normalsize] at (\tmp:#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd)
            {#6};
        }%
    }%
    \ifnum\theoutermost<#3\setcounter{outermost}{#3}\fi
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{onion}*{0.6in}
        \draw[fill=red!20,thick] (0,0) circle (1.53cm);
        \node[color=red,thick,font=\bfseries]  at (0,0) {My research};
        \annulus*[pear]{1}{0}{180}[Materials for composites]
        \annulus*[pear!80]{2}{0}{180}[Working through trial and errors to find parameters]
        \annulus*[pear!60]{3}{0}{180}[Conditions associated with pre and post heat treatment]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{20}{70}[Mechanical]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{0}{20}[Physical]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{70}{100}[Tribological]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{100}{150}[Microstructure(OM/SEM/TEM)]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{150}{180}[XRD]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{150}{180}[2($\theta$) and \\Bulk texture]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{100}{150}[Composites{,}\\Fracture{,}\\Wear track/debris]
        \annulus*[pear!25]{5}{70}{100}[Wear rate/COF]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{20}{40}[Hardness (Hv)]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{0}{20}[Density]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{40}{70}[Tensile (MPa)\\Yield (MPa)\\Elongation ($\delta$)]
        \annulus*[lavender!65]{1}{180}{360}[Materials for composites]
        \annulus*[lavender!55]{2}{180}{360}[Working through trial and errors to find parameters]
        \annulus*[lavender!45]{3}{180}{360}[Conditions associated with pre and post heat treatment]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{180}{200}[Physical]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{200}{250}[Mechanical]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{250}{280}[Tribological]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{280}{330}[Microstructure(OM/SEM/TEM)]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{330}{360}[XRD]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{180}{200}[Density]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{200}{220}[Hardness (Hv)]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{220}{250}[Tensile (MPa)\\Yield (MPa)\\Elongation ($\delta$)]
        \annulus*[lavender!25]{5}{250}{280}[Wear rate/COF]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{280}{330}[Composites{,}\\Fracture{,}\\Wear track/debris]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{330}{360}[2($\theta$) and \\Bulk texture]
        
    \end{onion}
    
\end{document}
```

**It produces the following output:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To change the font style, you need to modify the **text** property inside the **\annulus** definition. Specifically, you have to change this:

```latex
decoration={
    text along path,
    raise=-3pt,
    text align={align=center},
    reverse path=\rpTF,
    text=#6 % <-------------- HERE!
}
```

to this:

```latex
text={|\customannfont|#6}
```

and this:

```latex
\node[inner sep=0pt, %%% If there is text, print it
text width=#3*\layerwd*3+\layerwd,
align=center,
rotate=\rpTF,
font=\normalsize] at (\tmp:#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd) % <-------------- HERE!
{#6};
```

to this:

```latex
font=\customannfont] at (\tmp:#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd)
```

Note: Instead of using \customannfont, you could simply write the style of your font, like this:

```latex
%%% code before
text={|\bfseries\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont|#6}
%%% other code
font=\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont
```

to make the font 10pt and bold. However, I recommend defining your style before the **\annulus** definition, so you can change it in both places in the code by modifying it only once, like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\customannfont}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont}
```

Here is the complete code for making the font bold and bigger:[image: Modified chart]

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.05in]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{pear}{rgb}{0.82, 0.89, 0.19}
\definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.71, 0.49, 0.86}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text}
\newlength{\layerwd}
\newcounter{outermost}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{onion}{sm}{%*= draw axes; #1: thickness of each annulus
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setlength{\layerwd}{#2}%
        \setcounter{outermost}{0}
    }{%
        \foreach \A in {0,...,\theoutermost}{\draw[thick,] (0,0) circle (\A*\layerwd+\layerwd);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% define your custom font style
\newcommand{\customannfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont}
% *=text on a circular path; [optional fill color]; #3 layer;
% #4 start angle; #5 stop angle; #6 [optional text]
%% angles are counterclockwise in degrees
\NewDocumentCommand{\annulus}{sO{lightgray}mmmo}{%
    \filldraw[thick,fill=#2,] (#4:#3*\layerwd) %% start here
    arc [radius=#3*\layerwd, start angle=#4, delta angle=#5-#4] %% inner arc
    -- (#5:#3*\layerwd+\layerwd) %% move out
    arc [radius=#3*\layerwd+\layerwd, start angle=#5, delta angle=#4-#5,] %% outer arc
    -- cycle; %% Back to the beginnning
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{(#5-#4)/2 +#4} %% Locate the middle of the arc
    \IfNoValueF{#6}{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {%
            \begingroup
            %% text is always rightside-up:
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpTF}{ifthenelse(\tmp>180,"false","true")}
            \def\\{\space} %% A safety precaution, \\ = space on decorated text
            \path[rotate=\tmp-180,postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    text along path,
                    raise=-3pt,
                    text align={align=center},
                    reverse path=\rpTF,
                    text={|\customannfont|#6}
                }
            }] (0,0) circle (#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd);
            \endgroup
        }%% 
        {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpTF}{ifthenelse(\tmp>180,\tmp+90,\tmp-90)}
            \node[inner sep=0pt, %%% If there is text, print it
            text width=#3*\layerwd*3+\layerwd,
            align=center,
            rotate=\rpTF,
            font=\customannfont] at (\tmp:#3*\layerwd+0.5*\layerwd)
            {#6};
        }%
    }%
    \ifnum\theoutermost<#3\setcounter{outermost}{#3}\fi
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{onion}*{0.6in}
        \draw[fill=red!20,thick] (0,0) circle (1.53cm);
        \node[color=red,thick,font=\bfseries]  at (0,0) {My research};
        \annulus*[pear]{1}{0}{180}[Materials for composites]
        \annulus*[pear!80]{2}{0}{180}[Working through trial and errors to find parameters]
        \annulus*[pear!60]{3}{0}{180}[Conditions associated with pre and post heat treatment]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{20}{70}[Mechanical]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{0}{20}[Physical]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{70}{100}[Tribological]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{100}{150}[Microstructure(OM/SEM/TEM)]
        \annulus*[pear!40]{4}{150}{180}[XRD]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{150}{180}[2($\theta$) and \\Bulk texture]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{100}{150}[Composites{,}\\Fracture{,}\\Wear track/debris]
        \annulus*[pear!25]{5}{70}{100}[Wear rate/COF]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{20}{40}[Hardness (Hv)]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{0}{20}[Density]
        \annulus[pear!25]{5}{40}{70}[Tensile (MPa)\\Yield (MPa)\\Elongation ($\delta$)]
        \annulus*[lavender!65]{1}{180}{360}[Materials for composites]
        \annulus*[lavender!55]{2}{180}{360}[Working through trial and errors to find parameters]
        \annulus*[lavender!45]{3}{180}{360}[Conditions associated with pre and post heat treatment]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{180}{200}[Physical]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{200}{250}[Mechanical]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{250}{280}[Tribological]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{280}{330}[Microstructure(OM/SEM/TEM)]
        \annulus*[lavender!35]{4}{330}{360}[XRD]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{180}{200}[Density]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{200}{220}[Hardness (Hv)]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{220}{250}[Tensile (MPa)\\Yield (MPa)\\Elongation ($\delta$)]
        \annulus*[lavender!25]{5}{250}{280}[Wear rate/COF]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{280}{330}[Composites{,}\\Fracture{,}\\Wear track/debris]
        \annulus[lavender!25]{5}{330}{360}[2($\theta$) and \\Bulk texture]
        
    \end{onion}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! May you be blessed with the best of all blessings.

Answer (score 3):

The font can be specified with `\bfseries` and `\large`.

The code can be simplified using the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The text in the arcs is given to the key `arc data`. The direction of this text depends on the angle of the middle of the arc given by `\WCmidangle` which is used in the key `arc data dir`. This text is centered in the arc with `arc data pos=0.5`.

For the slices with 2 or 3 lines of text, an additional `\wheelchart` is used where `arc data pos` is specified separately for specific slices. Here, `slices style={fill=none}` is used.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
%%% uncomment the commented portion above \usepackage{wheelchart} package (from \ExplSyntaxOn) if compilation shows 'undefined control sequence' as error%%%
%\ExplSyntaxOn
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn
% \tl_gset:Nn {Ne}
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF {enF}
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn {Ne}
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nVTF} 
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn {en} 
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn {Ne} 
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn {ce} 
% \cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe 
% \cs_set:Npx \cs_set_eq:NN 
% \cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
%\ExplSyntaxOff
    \usepackage{wheelchart}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \bfseries\large
    \definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.71, 0.49, 0.86}
    \definecolor{pear}{rgb}{0.82, 0.89, 0.19}
    \pgfkeys{
      /wheelchart,
      arc data=\WCvarB,
      arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
      arc data pos=0.5,
      data=,
      slices style={fill=\WCcolor,draw=black,thick},
      total angle=180
    }
    \fill[red!20] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5] node[red] {My research};
    \foreach\WCstartangle/\WCarcdataposA/\WCarcdataposB/\WCcolorA/\WCcolorB/\WCcolorC/\WCcolorD/\WCcolorE in {%
      180/0.6/0.7/pear/pear!80/pear!60/pear!40/pear!25,
      0/0.4/0.3/lavender!65/lavender!55/lavender!45/lavender!35/lavender!25%
    }{
      \pgfkeys{
        /wheelchart,
        start angle=\WCstartangle
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolorA}
      \wheelchart[
        radius={1.5}{3}
      ]{%
        1/Materials for composites%
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolorB}
      \wheelchart[
        radius={3}{4.5}
      ]{%
        1/Working through trial and errors to find parameters%
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolorC}
      \wheelchart[
        radius={4.5}{6}
      ]{%
        1/Conditions associated with pre and post heat treatment%
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolorD}
      \wheelchart[
        radius={6}{7.5}
      ]{%
        30/XRD,
        50/{Microstructure (OM/SEM/TEM)},
        30/Tribological,
        50/Mechanical,
        20/Physical%
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolorE}
      \wheelchart[
        arc data pos{1}=\WCarcdataposA,
        arc data pos{2,4}=\WCarcdataposB,
        radius={7.5}{9}
      ]{%
        30/$2({\theta})$ and,
        50/{Composites,},
        30/{Wear rate/COF},
        30/Tensile (MPa),
        20/Hardness (Hv),
        20/Density%
      }
      \wheelchart[
        arc data pos{1}=1-\WCarcdataposA,
        radius={7.5}{9},
        slices style={fill=none}
      ]{%
        30/Bulk texture,
        50/{Fracture,},
        30/,
        30/Yield (MPa),
        20/,
        20/%
      }
      \wheelchart[
        arc data pos{2,4}=1-\WCarcdataposB,
        radius={7.5}{9},
        slices style={fill=none}
      ]{%
        30/,
        50/{Wear track/debris},
        30/,
        30/Elongation (${\delta}$),
        20/,
        20/%
      }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I highly admire your concern. I installed wheelchart.sty, and then compiled the MWE you posted. I got error stating 'undefined control sequence' at line 92 and many other errors at the same line 92.

Comment: @AhmedAafaq In that case, the version of expl3 is not up to date enough. It is probably sufficient to put the following _before_ `\usepackage{wheelchart}`:

`\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gset:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { enF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nVTF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { en }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn { ce }
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe \cs_set:Npx
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: Works!!! thank you very much.

Comment: Using \ExplSyntaxOn ......\ExplSyntaxOff compiles fine in TeXlive 2023, as i just checked it out on Texlive 2021 that it still produces errors, and the log shows "can be used only in preamble" at 105 line . Is there anyway to get rid of this error too?

Comment: @AhmedAafaq The code in the original answer (thus without `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff`) works perfectly if the LaTeX version is recent enough (2023-12-03 or newer). If the LaTeX version becomes older, more patch work will be necessary. I recommend updating to a newer version. If you really want to use the code in this answer with TeX Live 2021, proceed as follows. However, I don't have TeX Live 2021 so I can't test this, I can't guarantee that this will work and I do **not** recommend this. Place `%` before lines 2235, 2236 and 2237 of the file wheelchart.sty. (Continues in next comment)

Comment: Put the following _before_ `\usepackage{wheelchart}`:

`\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \tl_gset:Ne \tl_gset:Nx
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { xnF }
\cs_set_eq:NN \str_case:enF \str_case:xnF
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { xn }
\cs_set_eq:NN \str_case:en \str_case:xn
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe \cs_set:Npx
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
\cs_set_eq:NN \tl_set:Ne \tl_set:Nx
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nVTF }` (Continues in next comment)

Comment: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { xxTF }
\cs_set_eq:NN \str_if_eq:eeTF \str_if_eq:xxTF
\cs_set_eq:NN \clist_gput_right:Ne \clist_gput_right:Nx
\cs_set_eq:NN \clist_put_right:ce \clist_put_right:cx
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nxn , Nxo , Nnx , Nno , Nxx }
\cs_set_eq:NN \seq_set_split:Nen \seq_set_split:Nxn
\cs_set_eq:NN \seq_set_split:Nne \seq_set_split:Nnx
\cs_set_eq:NN \seq_set_split:Nee \seq_set_split:Nxx
\ExplSyntaxOff`

It might be necessary to place `%` before line 237 of the file wheelchart.sty. (End of explanation)